# How can i include an associative array in a simple array in php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I wanted to make a JSON file using data from my MySql Database.

I'm using the following code to make a json file.

```
<?php

 $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','mydb1');
 $return_arr = array();
 $sql = "select * from questions";
 $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
 $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
 $row_array['ques'] = $row['ques'];
 $row_array['ans'] = $row['ans'];
 array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
 }
 mysqli_close($con);
 $b = json_encode($return_arr);
 $f = fopen("test.json","w");
 fwrite($f,$b);
 fclose($f);


?>
```

It is giving me the following output :

```
[{"id":"1","ques":"New Delhi is capital of India?","ans":"1"},{"id":"2","ques":"India has 5 neighboring countries.","ans":"0"}]
```

But i want my result to like :

```
{"questions" : {"question" : [{"id":"1","ques":"New Delhi is capital of India?","ans":"1"},{"id":"2","ques":"India has 5 neighboring countries.","ans":"0"}]}
```

So that i can use it properly in android.How can i do this?
Can anyone please help?

Or can you please help me in how can i use it in android without changing my array.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple just change this line

```
$b = json_encode($return_arr);
```

to this line

```
$b = json_encode(['questions' => ['questions' => $return_arr]]);
```

When you were saving to JSON file you were saving as array ob objects when you want to save it as a key value pair then you have to specify the key.

Also a quick tip if you want your JSON pretty output you can use **`JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`** as your second parameter like this

```
$b = json_encode(['questions' => $return_arr], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

see here http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#refsect1-function.json-encode-parameters

Comment: Can you please check my edited question i changed it a bit.
I need a little bit different JSON. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot.
You saved my day. :)